# https requests are going to 80 port

Tags: nginx, flask

I'm using flask + nginx
All of the requests to my domains, that use flask are going to 80 port, even if it's https connection
My config for domain:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSV1.2;

    #ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
    location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

So, I'm issuing redirect loop, and in access.log I see, that all of the requests are going to 80 port. What am I doing wrong? Certificates are from Let's Encrypt.

Comment: Why do you have proxy_pass for http when you want to do redirect?

Comment: @mx0, I tested out, what's wrong, and forgot to remove this. But, unfortunately, removing this line doesn't solve the problem =(